# How to synchronize Odoo(OpenERP)-ORM with Postgres tables

Tags: orm, odoo, synchronization

When openerp modules are uninstalled the associated tables in the postgres database still exist. Is there anyway to synchronize the OpenERP modules with the ORM model to remove those tables and assigned user to it only. B/c it gives no sense to keep the tables without the application which access it.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a routine that starts with the ir_model table and look for tables in the schema that don't have a matching entry in ir_model.  You will have to be careful of transient (osv_memory in version 6 parlance) tables and also models with _auto = False which is usually done to create database views.

Comment: Thanks @Adrian Merrall, if i'm not mistaken it is a query that i'll include in the orm model by referring those components that you mentioned but have you tried that?

Comment: I don't think a simple query will do it as you will have to deal with transient models and views.  Actually thinking about it, possibly it will as you could run a query that lists tables in PG that aren't in the ir_model table.  I haven't tried to do this myself but I think what you suggest is a good idea to clean up databases after some module churn and something I will need to put on my to-do list.